# Database not created because of defining "app_label" META in Django

Tags: python, database, django, meta

I am designing a simple model in Django(1.3) which has 3 fields and some META options.

```
class DataSource(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    priority        = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    read_only       = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Data Source"
        verbose_name_plural = "Data Sources"
        app_label = 'My Admin'
```

Now, this model's table isn't being created in the database when I `syncdb`.

What could be the reason?

Should I remove it?

If I want to keep it, what is(are) the solution(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label)

> #### `app_label`
>
> If a model exists outside of the standard `models.py` (for instance, if the app’s models are in submodules of `myapp.models`), the model must define which app it is part of:
>
> ```
> app_label = 'myapp'
> ```

The app_label must be an app name. You don't have an app called "My Admin".